# How to make dotnet core select a lower version?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have several versions of dotnet core in my system. But .Net Core project selects the latest version for building the project. Is there anything I can do to make sure that the project selects the correct version? I am using Visual Studio for development.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To list all the versions of dotnet core installed in the system, open the command prompt and type the following command:

```sh
dotnet --info
```

If you want to know the specific version used for running the application, go to the folder location, and type `cmd` in the address bar at the top to open command prompt. Then type this in command prompt.

```sh
dotnet --version
```

If you want to change this version to some other version installed in the system, type the following in the command prompt.

```sh
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 2.2.100 --force
```

Here, I want to use `2.2.100`. This will create a global.json file. This will tell Visual Studio which version of .NET Core to use.

This is the content of global.json file.

```json
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.100"
  }
}
```

By following this, you can switch between .NET Core versions. Otherwise, Visual Studio will only take the latest version installed.

#### Further Reading:

- [`dotnet` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet)
- [`dotnet new` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new)

Answer (score 21):

> How to make dotnet core select a lower version?

From your description, I suppose you want to specify the framework to target when using the `dotnet new` command to create Asp.net Core application. If that is the case, you could use the `-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>` property, for example: use the following command create a Asp.net Core 3.1 MVC application and named "aspnetcoreapp".

```
dotnet new mvc -f netcoreapp3.1 -o aspnetcoreapp
```

[**Note**] The `-f|--framework <FRAMEWORK>` property **available since .NET Core 3.0 SDK**. More detail information about this property, see [dotnet new command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new#console).

[image]

If you want to select the lower version, you could try to use Visual Studio 2019 to create an application, then after selecting the project template, you could select the .net core version like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer:). But this is not what I want. I have an already existing project that is running in `.NET Core 2.2.100`. I have the required version installed but I also have .NET 5. When building the project, Visual studio is taking .NET 5. This is causing some problems for me. I have found the solution and wrote an answer. Please see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Create a new backend with sdk .NET 5

```
dotnet new webapi -n ProjectName -f net5.0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create global files in the root folders where you want specific versions.
You can run the following in the command line in the selected folder:

```
dotnet new global
```

This creates a new file called "global.json". You can open this file and edit the version number. You can list all available SDK versions using `dotnet --list-sdks`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x) he complete documentation on how you can set versions. You may want to consider using "latestFeature" or "latestPatch" (detailed in the documentation). These help as the hardcoded .net core SDK versions might change over time.

Comment: To anyone reading this, the switch is actually `globaljson`.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio will use the version of .NET Core that was selected while creating the project. If you have already created the project then you can set the version of .NET Core for the project from Visual Studio and on next build Visual Studio will use the configured version of .NET Core. See steps below to set the version of .NET Core if you have already created the project.

1. Open project solution file in Visual Studio and Go to Solution Explorer
2. In Solution Explorer, right click the project and click on Properties to open Project Properties Windows
3. In Project Properties Window --> Application Tab --> Target Framework Dropdownlist --> Select the version of .NET Core that you want to use
4. Build the solution.

Comment: It doesn't select the target dotnet version. It's selecting the latest version in my system.

Comment: @StarLord, there is a possibility that building project is being instructed from elsewhere in the Visual Studio. What do you have in "Right Click the Project --> Select Properties --> Build Events Tab"?

Comment: I don't have anything written in that tab. I have found the solution to this. Please see the accepted answer. I really appreciate your help:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the --framework flag to specify a specific the target framework. For example if you want to create a .NET 6.0 web API, but your current .NET SDK is 7.0. You can do this:

```
dotnet dotnet new webapi --framework "net6.0" -name <YOUR_PROJECT_NAME>
```

This is the documentation for your reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new.

This is of course assuming you are creating a new project. Otherwise, you need to update your .NET version in the .csproj file like this:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```